# Stereo calibration using two cameras and 3D reconstruction of an Object?

Tags: java, graphics, opencv, computer-vision, javacv

I have two cameras setup as shown in following picture:

[image]

What I have with this setup:

- Top view of this green object with `(x1,y1)` as its 2D image coordinates.
- Side view of this green object with `(x2,y2)` as its 2D image coordinates.

How can I trace/identify real world 3D coordinates `(x,y,z)` of this green object via these two cameras (i.e combination of top view image and side view image)?

I know how to calibrate single camera using JavaCV/OpenCV but I don't know how perform stereo calibration other stuff using JavaCV/OpenCV.

What is the step-by-step procedure for doing such stereo calibration via two cameras?

What would be the output (e.g., intrinsic matrix, distortion etc.) of such a stereo calibration process and how can I use that output in order to compute the real world 3D coordinates of this green object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the picture,I think you may face problem in implementing stereo algorithms for your a setup. The stereo rectification works well when the cameras are almost fronto-parallel . For your camera setup, you can hardly get any rectified image on which you could find any disparity matching.

Comment: ok.. if i put both of my cameras parallely(as u suggested) seperated by a cirtain distance... my ques. is that :- can i achive the same goal (3D reconstruction of green object) with this new camera setup.??

Comment: You could get the 3d coordinates of the portion which can be seen by both cameras, You could refer some which include some point cloud libraries and plot all the points in youtube.. You could understand well if you refer those videos. If you specify your application clearly I could answer to your point..

Comment: yeah sure!!..  basically i m working on a paint simulator project. in which i have to track and identify nozzle like object's real world coordinates (in front of target screen/computer screen) in order to render virtual paint on d computer screen.

Comment: http://www.vision.deis.unibo.it/smatt/stereo.htm

refer the 2nd article which could answer most of the questions about stereo vision(stero vision and applications)..

Answer (score 1):

Hi the following blog will answer all your questions...
      http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html

No image was uploaded.. Just check  or else you could find theoritical concepts
 from the book  [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)

or for the actual code implementing with cameras one can refer to
               http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVdKK_5l9XU&feature=plcp

Comment: but how to implement stereo calibration and 3d reconstruction with cameras and not with just taking images.

Comment: You could check for the code which is present in link
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVdKK_5l9XU&feature=plcp
there was a link attached to this video

Comment: i will look into it.. thnx. :-)